# Are there any R Packages for Graphs (shortest path, etc.)?

Tags: r, graph, graph-theory, shortest-path

I know that R is statistical pkg, but probably there is library to work with graphs and find shortest path btw 2 nodes.

PS actually, I've found igraph and e1071, which one is better?
Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, there's a [Task View](http://mirrors.softliste.de/cran/) that gathers a fair number of the graph-related Packages. (The page linked to is a CRAN portal, which uses iframes, so i can't directly link to the Graph Task View. So from the page linked to here, click on *Task Views* near the top of the LHS column, then click on the Task View ***gR***, near the bottom of the list.

Among the Packages there, [igraph](http://mirrors.softliste.de/cran/web/packages/igraph/index.html), for instance, has graph-theoretic functions such as you have mentioned in your Q.

igraph versus e1071--well, igraph is coded in C; it's very fast. I have not compared it with e1071 though.

What i do know is that these two packages differ a great deal in scope: e1071 is a collection of functions (at least originally) for a University course (i believe the unusual name 'e1071' refers to the course identifier), while. e1071 indeed contains a graph theoretic functions, but the majority of the Package's functions are directed to machine learning.

iGraph on the other hand is a dedicated graph theoretic Package. iGraph has many more dedicated functions, as well as constructors for a number of common graph types.